# Angular route does not resolve service

Tags: angularjs

I've been scratching my head over this one for a couple hours now, and after a good amount of searching I haven't found a helpful solution.

As the title state, my dependencies are not being resolved by Angular's route provider. This is the error:

`Unknown provider: testServiceProvider <- testService <- testService`

My compiled Javascript file (`app.js`) looks like this:

```js
'use-strict';

var app = angular.module('test-app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            resolve: {
                testService: function (testService) {
                    console.log(testService.message);
                }
            }
        })
}]);

app.factory('apiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    function url(endpoint) {
        return '/api/v1' + endpoint;
    }

    return {
        user: {
            authenticated: function () {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: url('/user/authenticated')});
            },

            login: function (token) {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: url('/user/login'), cache: false, headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Basic ' + token
                }});
            },

            logout: function () {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: url('/user/logout')});
            },

            model: function () {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: url('/user/data')});
            }
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('testService', function () {
    return {
        message: 'Hello world'
    };
});

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, apiService, testService) {
    $scope.user = {
        authenticated: false,
        error: '',
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    $scope.login_button = 'Log in';

    $scope.isAuthenticated = function () {
        return $scope.user.authenticated;
    }

    $scope.needsAuthentication = function () {
        if (!$scope.user.authenticated) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    $scope.logIn = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();

        $scope.login_button = 'Please wait...';

        var token = btoa($scope.user.username + ':' + $scope.user.password);

        apiService.user.login(token).then(function (success) {
            $scope.user = success.data.user;

            $scope.user.authenticated = true;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.user.error = 'Please try logging in again.';

            $scope.login_button = 'Log in';
        });
    };
}]);
```

As far as I can tell, everything should be resolving fine; am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think the problem in an alias. You use testService as alias for your resolving. $injector could be confused. Try to rename it for example: `resolve: {
                testData: function (testService) {
                    console.log(testService.message);
                }
            }` and rename it in controller as well.

Comment: @Errorpro It returns essentially the same error: `Unknown provider: testServiceProvider <- testService <- testData`.

Comment: @Errorpro actually, I believe that there must have been a separate cause for error when I posted that last comment, because now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: @Errorpro yes, is there any way I can mark your comment as the answer? I'm not fully familiar with how Stack Overflow works but I'd like to close this thread.

Comment: I've created an answer ;) 'cause i don't know too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in an alias. You use testService as alias for your resolving. $injector could be confused. Try to rename it for example:

```
resolve: { testData: function (testService) { console.log(testService.message); } }
```

and rename it in controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the service,

change

**From:**

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, apiService, testService)
```

**To:**

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http','apiService','testService' ,function ($scope, $http, apiService, testService)
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me; I'd actually been doing this beforehand, but forgot to add it back in (I removed it while debugging). Adding it back produces the same error, however.